# Precision and recall eval_metrics for labels and predictions of different number of elements in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am having a problem with registering precision and recall as eval_metrics in Tensorflow. My labels and predictions don't have the same number of elements, so I can't use the already built-in functions. I have the function to calculate the precision and recall, but I can't seem to get precision_update_op and recall_update_op. Any ideas how I can get that from having labels, predictions and the previously mentioned functions for calculation precision and recall? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is an simple example of how to build your own metrics. I will demonstrate for `mean`, you should be able to adapt for the above mentioned as well.

```
def mean_metrics(values):
   """ For mean, there are two variables that are 
 required to hold the sum and the total number of variables"""

   # total sum
   total = tf.Variable(initial_value=0., dtype=tf.float32, name='total')

   # total count
   count = tf.Variable(initial_value=0., dtype=tf.float32, name='count')

   # Update total op by updating total with the sum of the values
   update_total_op = tf.assign_add(total, tf.cast(tf.reduce_sum(values), tf.float32))

   # Update count op by updating the total size of the values
   update_count_op = tf.assign_add(count, tf.cast(tf.size(tf.squeeze(values)), tf.float32))

   # Mean
   mean = tf.div(total, count, 'value')

   # Mean update op
   update_op = tf.div(update_total_op, update_count_op, 'value')

   return mean, update_op
```

Testing the above code:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
values = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None])

mean, mean_op = mean_metrics(values)

with tf.Session() as sess:
   tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
   print(sess.run([mean, mean_op], {values:[1.,2.,3.]}))
   print(sess.run([mean, mean_op], {values:[4.,5.,6.]}))

#output
#[nan, 2.0]
#[2.0, 3.5]
```